# How do you calculate the speed of air when it fills a vacuum of 1 cm³?

Tags: vectors, velocity, air

At different heights, atmospheric pressure is different. If a vacuum was created of say 1 cm³, how would i calculate the velocity of air filling it back in. The adjacent layer of air would obviously be faster than the further ones, I want to calculate the one that is touching the vacuum's edges before it collapses.

Comment: how big is the opening?

Comment: @Rick the surface area of the vacuum cube(1 cm³)